# ios, how to decrease the FPS of the video stream from the camera

Tags: ios, video

I need to decrease the frame rate of the video stream coming from the camera of an iPhone.

This is the code I use:

```
[...]
_captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
if( [_captureSession canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480]) {
    [_captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Could not initialize 640x480 video stream");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

AVCaptureDevice *videoCaptureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
NSError *error = nil;    

if ([videoCaptureDevice lockForConfiguration:&error]) {
    AVCaptureDeviceFormat *format =  [videoCaptureDevice activeFormat];
    NSArray *supportedFPS = format.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges;

    CMTime maxFrameDuration;
    float maxSeconds = FLT_MIN;

    for(AVFrameRateRange *fpsRange in supportedFPS) {
        float currentSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(fpsRange.maxFrameDuration);
        if(currentSeconds > maxSeconds) maxFrameDuration =fpsRange.maxFrameDuration;

        NSLog(@"Supported range. Max frame rate: %f (min frame duration %f) -  
                                 Min frame rate: %f (max frame duration %f)",
        fpsRange.maxFrameRate, 
        CMTimeGetSeconds(fpsRange.minFrameDuration),  
        fpsRange.minFrameRate,  
        CMTimeGetSeconds(fpsRange.maxFrameDuration));
    } // for

    NSLog(@"Setting min/max duration for frames to %f", CMTimeGetSeconds(maxFrameDuration));
    [videoCaptureDevice setActiveVideoMaxFrameDuration:maxFrameDuration];
    [videoCaptureDevice setActiveVideoMinFrameDuration:maxFrameDuration];
    [...]
 } // lockForConf
```

The idea is to

- get the current format, once set the size of the video stream;
- get the array with available ranges for frame rate
- find the one with the longest frame duration
- set the min/max frame duration of the capture device to the maximum value.

The only log message printed in the for loop is:

```
Supported range. Max frame rate: 30.000000 (min frame duration 0.033333) - 
Min frame rate: 2.000000 (max frame duration 0.500000)
```

Despite it seems possible to set the FPS to 2 frames per second, the camera still outputs a lot of frames per second. I don't know how to get the FPS of the video stream, but the camera is definitely not serving only 2 per second.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Did you get to resolve your issue?

Comment: I wasn't able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use activeVideoMinFrameDuration and activeVideoMaxFrameDuration of ACCaptureDevice to update Frames of the session.

Like:

```
[captureDevice setActiveVideoMaxFrameDuration:CMTimeMake(2, 1)];
[captureDevice setActiveVideoMinFrameDuration:CMTimeMake(2, 1)];
```

You can also refer: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1389290-activevideominframeduration